# SwiftUI: Path .anchorPreference

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to set a SwiftUI Path .anchorPreference to center.

I have looked at many examples on SO, but could not make it work. Apple documentation on this is zero.

```
import SwiftUI

struct PatternScene: View {

    let pattern = Path { path in
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 50))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 250, y: 50))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 250, y: 250))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 250))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100))
    }

    var body: some View {
        self.pattern
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
            //.anchorPreference(key: <#T##PreferenceKey.Protocol#>, value: <#T##Anchor<A>.Source#>) { anchor in}
    }

}

struct PatternScene_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        PatternScene()
    }
}
```

appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a data and key `struct` that conforms to `PreferenceKey` for `.anchorPreference(...)` to work:

Something like this:

```
struct MyTextPreferenceData {
    let viewIdx: Int
    let bounds: Anchor<CGRect>
}

struct MyTextPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    typealias Value = [MyTextPreferenceData]

    static var defaultValue: [MyTextPreferenceData] = []

    static func reduce(value: inout [MyTextPreferenceData], nextValue: () -> [MyTextPreferenceData]) {
        value.append(contentsOf: nextValue())
    }
}

struct PatternScene: View {
    let idx: Int

    let pattern = Path { path in
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 50))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 250, y: 50))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 250, y: 250))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 250))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100))
    }

    var body: some View {
        self.pattern
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .anchorPreference(key: MyTextPreferenceKey.self, value: .bounds, transform: { [MyTextPreferenceData(viewIdx: self.idx, bounds: $0)] })
    }
}

struct PatternScene_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        PatternScene(idx: 0)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here it is a demo of approach how this could be done

[image: SwiftUI Anchor center usage]

Testing code:

```
struct TestPatternScene: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            PatternScene()
                .overlayPreferenceValue(PatternSceneCenterKey.self) { pref in
                    GeometryReader { g in
                        if pref.center != nil {
                            Circle()
                                .fill(Color.red)
                                .frame(width: 4, height: 4)
                                .position(g[pref.center!]) // !! read stored center point (already converted into .local space)
                        }
                    }
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

Main code:

```
struct PatternSceneCenter { // Pref value to store anchor
    var center: Anchor<CGPoint>? = nil
}

struct PatternSceneCenterKey: PreferenceKey { // Pref key 
    typealias Value = PatternSceneCenter

    static var defaultValue: PatternSceneCenter = PatternSceneCenter()

    static func reduce(value: inout PatternSceneCenter, 
        nextValue: () -> PatternSceneCenter) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
}

struct PatternScene: View {

    let pattern = Path { path in
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 50))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 250, y: 50))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 250, y: 250))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 250))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100))
    }

    var body: some View {
        self.pattern
            .fill(Color.yellow)
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: 100, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: 100)
            .anchorPreference(key: PatternSceneCenterKey.self, 
                value: .center) { PatternSceneCenter(center: $0) } // store center anchor of current view into our custom pref value
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks @Asperi! It works but I don't quite understand what code is doing. And form the post bellow, looks like anchorPreference is the right tool for the job?
https://swiftui-lab.com/communicating-with-the-view-tree-part-2/

Comment: Well... Anchor is a reference to some coordinate data (rect or point) in a view, where it is stored (via preferences), so later via `GeometryProxy` that reference can be transferred into real coordinate data of current coordinate space.

Comment: you are right, thanks again! I voted the other answer as it was more aligned to what I asked.